# Django Rest Framework, updating nested serialized data

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm new to using the Django Rest Framework and serialized data, I'm trying to update a nested serializer but ran into a wall, I've looked around but most people have problems in the serializers.py side while I can't even get into def update without an error, these are my classes:

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics
from api.serializers import ProfileSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from api.models import Profile
from django.http import JsonResponse

class ProfileView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def get(self, request):
        profile = Profile.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(profile, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = Profile.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
        data = request.POST
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(profile, data=data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
        else:
            print(serializer.errors)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from api.models import Profile

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','username','first_name','last_name','email','last_login','date_joined','is_active')

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id','phone','birth_date','user')

        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            #Cant get here
            print("hey")
            return instance
```

**Sample structure**

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "phone": "XXXXXX",
        "birth_date": "2017-06-29",
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "xxxxx",
            "first_name": "XXXXX",
            "last_name": "XXXX",
            "email": "xxxxxxx@gmail.com",
            "last_login": "2017-06-29T15:16:11.438818Z",
            "date_joined": "2017-06-23T16:48:38Z",
            "is_active": true
        }
    }
]
```

**My current error:**
(Post Data: phone = 0000000)

```
AttributeError at /profile/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You see this error because you are passing queryset instead of instance to serializer `__init__`. To solve error change this:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    profile = Profile.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
```

to this:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
```

in other words instead of queryset, which returned by `filter` you need Profile instance returned by `get`.

**UPD**

to update nested user try this (didnt test it, let me know if this have any errors):

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    user = validated_data.get('user')
    instance.user.first_name = user.get('first_name')
    instance.user.save()

    print("hey")
    return instance
```

Comment: Awesome! That works for normal updating, I can change the data on the upper level (phone) but could you help me out in updating the data for the nested set? (Changing the username for example)

I gave it a try posting `user.email = something` but got the following error `The .update() method does not support writable nested fields by default.` how do I write my custom update method to do that then? Thanks again

Comment: I still get the same error, it looks like it would work, but I don't seem to be getting into that function at all, when I post data it tries the default update instead of my custom one, do I need to specify it in my view using .update() or something?

Comment: @Amirgem oh, I see, remove update from Meta class. This should be inside Serializer class directly, an the same level as Meta.

Comment: I was about to type that that was the mistake haha, thanks never!!

Comment: I want to show the data into the fields at the time of updation do you know how do we do that in nested serializing...... because otherwise I am getting null or blank fields, so if I edit one field it shows me an error, that these fields can't be blank or null.... please help.... Thank You

Comment: @NikhilBhardwaj sorry, I dont know how to help you.

Answer (score 8):

Found myself in similar situation and I was able to solve as below.Hope it helps.

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
    user_serializer = UserSerializer()
    super(self.__class__, self).update(instance,validated_data)
    super(UserSerializer,user_serializer).update(instance.user,user_data)
    return instance
```

Comment: You are instantiating a UserSerializer without an object or a "data" keyword argument. I believe this is because user_data is not exactly fit to pass to UserSerializer. But it is still an incorrect way to use the Serializer, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and resolved it using a workaround. First let me explain my scenario. When a SUBMIT button is pressed on a JS page, it will trigger a REST API which will increment the count of an existing DB item by 1. So I parsed the contents of the incoming JSON request into a variable, say A. But since this variable was immutable, so I created a new variable say X, and then added the value in a format which could be sent to the serializable class like so:-
`X = {'item_name': A["item_name"], 'count_of_votes': last_count + 1}`
Then
`serializer_class_Object = serializer_class(existing_object_ref, data=X)`